# Some events are not received by firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I would like to use "firebase": "^7.14.0" in my javascript web project to track my users behaviour. My problem is, that some of the events seem to get lost. They are fired as i can see on the console with the google analytics debuig extension but are not shown in the firebase console debug view.

My code looks like this:

```
analytics().logEvent('select_content', {
        content_type: 'MyGame',
        item_id: 'JoinGame_Clicked',
    });
```

For an example: I fired 5 of those events but only 2 are shown in the debug view.

What can cause this behaviour?

Comment: From what I see on https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web (assuming it's about Firebase for the Web, not iOS nor Android), the call is not analytics().logEvent but analytics.logEvent() ?!

Comment: Thx for your answer. But this shouldnt be wrong as I receive the event around 50% of the time.

Comment: Do you notice scenarios / situations where it's complete anyway ? Or it is always missing some hits ? Are they missing in volume or some hits are never collected ?
Can you confirm the platform architecture you are using ? Firebase Web ? Which Firebase Analytics ?

Comment: Do that extension work in your context ?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom
What does it show ?

Comment: Could you be exposed to the quota of "up to 500 different Analytics Event types in your app" https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web